# SQLite выводит лист но при проверке слова не равны

Tags: sql

```
import sqlite3

connect = sqlite3.connect(
    'TStal\\TStal_Equipment1.sql', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = connect.cursor()

cursor.execute(
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS equipment1 (ID TEXT, item TEXT)')
connect.commit()

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO equipment1 VALUES (?, ?)", [1, 'сатурн'])
connect.commit()

if 'сатурн' in cursor.execute("SELECT item FROM equipment1").fetchall():
    print('y')
else:
    print('n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Условие там получается, "присутствует ли строка 'сатурн' в списке ", но список содержит не строки, а кортежи строк [('сатурн',)], нужно распаковать.